# При запуске make возникает ошибка "make: *** Нет правила для сборки цели «main.cpp», требуемой для «all». Останов." В чём она может заключаться?

Tags: makefile

Сам Makefile имеет следующий вид:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp InitializingBoard.cpp BoardStatus.cpp FigureMove.cpp ShessHod.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=chessviz

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
    
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где может быть проблема

Comment: потому что цель для cpp выглядит где то так `%.o: %.cpp`

Comment: как минимум надо убрать переменную SOURCES из пререквизитов цели all.

Comment: @KoVadim, «цель для cpp« выглядит примерно так: `%.cpp: любимый.редактор здравый.смысл`

Comment: Должна поменяться только эта строчка: OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)?
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:%.o: %.cpp)